Is "Docta Totam Vitam Manent" genuine Latin for “What you learn in life stays with you”?
I came across a site that claims the Latin for “What you learn in life stays with you” is "docta totam vitam manent", but I don't know if it's an accurate translation.

Not quite: Docta totam vitam manent means: "The things that were taught stay for the whole life" – or, more idiomatically, given that the organisation using this motto appears to be a training institution – "what we teach you will stay with you for your whole life."
It is also not particularly good Latin: as already suggested by my second translation, the idea really calls for the future tense. Also, "for the whole life" is better expressed as tota (or omni) vita or per totam (omnem) vitam. So I would rather say:

Docta per totam vitam manebunt.

Edit: Thinking more about this, I also have strong reservations about using docta this way. Docere can take two accusatives, the person that is taught (acc. pers.) and the matter that is taught (acc. rei), but the passive participle seems to very regularly refer to a learned/educated person, and almost never to some subject or lesson that has been taught. Doctrinae might be a more appropriate word.

It is, but I think a much better phrasing is "Res quas doceris remanent tecum per totam vitam.".

Out of curiosity, why did you go with doceri instead of discere? Either might work here, but the distinction between learning and being taught is worth making.

@JoonasIlmavirta Because "docta" in the original sentence means "taught", rather than "having learned".

Fair enough, it was in the suggested Latin translation. My point was more that it wasn't in the English original, and the distinction may have escaped the OP. Discussing one's choices instead of just giving a translation makes for a better answer (cf. Sebastian's answer), but your translation here does indeed work.
